# jenkins throwing access denied

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to run a basic maven project through jenkins for artifact I am using myMavenRepo,I have done the configuration in pom.xml for myMavenRepo.write and myMavenRepo.read and added settings.xml file in .m2 folder below is the setting.xml

```
'''
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>myMavenRepo.read</id>
            <username>myMavenRepo</username>
            <password>${yourHttpAuthReadPassword}</password>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>myMavenRepo.write</id>
            <username>myMavenRepo</username>
            <password>${yourHttpAuthWritePassword}</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
'''
```

I have done below configuration for myMavenRepo.read and myMavenRepo.write in pom.xml

```
'''
<project>
    ...
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>myMavenRepo.read</id>
            <url>${myMavenRepo.read.url}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    ...
</project>
'''
'''
<project>
    ...
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>myMavenRepo.write</id>
            <url>${myMavenRepo.write.url}</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
    ...
</project>
'''
```

while running the job I am specifying "clean deploy" command but its giving error saying
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project demo: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-20200502.130925-1 from/to myMavenRepo.write 
Access denied to:

Please let me know how to fix it

Comment: You mention `setting.xml` in your question. Please check if the actual file name is `settings.xml` (plural, so it ends with 's'): https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: yes its settings.xml

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem and the only way for me to deploy and artifact is temporary "disable http auth" from the mymavenrepo console...